# Cross-validating pull-requests

Tags: gitlab, branch, pull-request

I share a repository with my colleagues and want to know if it is possible to enforce:

- That no one can commit/push to the main-branch. (Only merge/pull-requests)
- That every issue has to be validated by someone else.

I have googled quite a bit, but I think I'm missing some important keywords here.

Comment: *Git* has no built in controls of this sort, but *Git* has no pull requests either. GitHub and Bitbucket provide PRs, but which of these do you mean? Add the right tag and/or update the text here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible.